# Simple and fast presentation of theory about projections and universality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, universal-property, projection, map-projections

I would to learn what happens in a projection about universality.
 I searched in google and i found this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(mathematics)

Let's conside that we refer in $Set$ category or more specific in projetion of cartesian product.

The quick question is why these projections preserve universality??

Comment: What do you mean by "universality"? The categorical product is characterized by a universal property, but this is not something that can be "preserved" by a mapping.

Comment: The above article says "The commutativity of this diagram is the "universality of the projection π", for any map f and set X."

Comment: That diagram seems to be trying to say the following: a morphism $\pi : A \to B$ is a projection, if for any $f : X \to B$ there is a morphism $\bar f : X \to A$ such that $\pi \circ \bar f = f$. Note that by taking $f = \mathrm{id}_B: B \to B$ you can see that the projections are precisely the morphisms with a right inverse. This doesn't really have anything to do with projections from the product; according to the definition I just gave, in $\mathsf{Set}$, the projections are precisely the surjective mappings.

Comment: You say "This doesn't really have anything to do with projections from the product" but the product preserve universal property via projections as above projection of article and this make sense. Also, the above article in this section reffer in sets, so maybe the definition of projections is the same in category $Set$. Do you know why the projection of article preserve universality?

Comment: @MeesdeVries I have a question regarding the commutative-ness of diagram: $f:X\to B$ may 
 not be surjective, and $\pi: A\to B$ is supposed to be surjective. Then how the diagram commutes wrt an element $b\in B$ when $b\notin \mathrm{im}f$?

Comment: @bruin I recommend you write down a small example to strengthen your understanding.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I guess I figured it out: if $f$ is non-surjective, then the unique $\overline f$ (which is determined by $f$ and $\pi$) will be non-surjective (onto A) as well.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Regarding the original question, my understanding of your comment "in Set, the projections are precisely the surjective mappings" is that the claim in Wikipedia "The commutativity of this diagram is the universality of the projection $\pi$, for any map $f$ and set $X$." can be rephrased as "The commutativity of this diagram is the universality of any surjective mapping $\pi$, for any map $f$ and set $X$.".  I.e., the claim only requires the surjective property of a projection, not relying on the idempotent property of a projection. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @bruin, I don't mean this to be rude: the comment section of a three year old question is not the place to ask follow-up questions. Ask a new question, linking to this one if you must have the context available.